# Jsoup and ListFragment Issue

Tags: listview, android-fragments, android-studio, jsoup

I have created a number of object manually in an arraylist which then show in a fragment list. I am trying to use jsoup to access a website link and then get a certain css selector. I have tested it and it is working in intellj but when I try to use it within android studio it keeps giving a null pointed.

Can anyone help with this and specifically on the Postexecute I want to update a variable in the product object and not specifically put something into a view.

Please not in the example below I have called the method in the oncreate and I will then want to call it from the long press context menu under Update.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
public class MainActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private Product product;

    private ProductRetrievingTask mainTask;
    private ProductRetrieverImpl retriever;
    String ben;
    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    private ProductAdapter productAdapter;
    private static MainActivityListFragment instance = null;

    //Activity when the main activity calls it
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle saveInstantceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(saveInstantceState);
        instance = this;
        new JSOUP().execute();    

        //
        //        String[] values = new String[]{"ben", "cathy", "mum", "ben", "cathy", "mum", "ben", "cathy", "mum", "ben", "cathy", "mum", "ben", "cathy", "mum"};
        //
        //        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        //
        //        setListAdapter(adapter);


        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini", 15.99, "#offerPrice_262795", "http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/black--decker-ni-cad-cordless-drill-driver---18v-623805", "http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/Apple_MC770LL_A_32GB_iPad_2_with_758439.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini2", 51.99, "#CSS", "http://www.bbc.co.uk", "http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/Apple_MC770LL_A_32GB_iPad_2_with_758439.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini3", 152.99, "#CSS", "http://www.bbc.co.uk", "http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/Apple_MC770LL_A_32GB_iPad_2_with_758439.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini4", 153.99, "#CSS", "http://www.bbc.co.uk", "http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/Apple_MC770LL_A_32GB_iPad_2_with_758439.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini5", 154.99, "#CSS", "http://www.bbc.co.uk", "http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/Apple_MC770LL_A_32GB_iPad_2_with_758439.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini", 15.99, "#CSS", "http://www.bbc.co.uk", "http://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/Apple_MC770LL_A_32GB_iPad_2_with_758439.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini2", 151.99, "#CSS", "http://www.funktiongolf.co.uk", "http://lightswitchtimer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/lights-for-pets.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini3", 152.99, "#CSS", "http://www.funktiongolf.co.uk", "http://lightswitchtimer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/lights-for-pets.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini4", 153.99, "#CSS", "http://www.funktiongolf.co.uk", "http://lightswitchtimer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/lights-for-pets.jpg"));
        products.add(new Product("New ipad mini5", 154.99, "#CSS", "http://www.funktiongolf.co.uk", "http://lightswitchtimer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/lights-for-pets.jpg"));


        productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), products);


        setListAdapter(productAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    public static MainActivityListFragment getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


        //Called when an item is clicked
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        launchProductDetail(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.long_press_menu, menu);
    }


    public void priceUpdate(Product product, double newPrice) {
        product.setOldprice(product.getPrice());

        product.setPrice(newPrice);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        final int rowPosition = info.position;


        //Returns the id of which menu item we select
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.delete:
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                adb.setTitle("Delete?");
                adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        productAdapter.remove(productAdapter.getItem(rowPosition));
                        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                adb.show();

                Log.d("Menu Click", "We pressed delete");

                // return true;
                break;
            case R.id.update:





                break;
            case R.id.website:


                product = productAdapter.getItem(rowPosition);
                if (product != null)
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(product.getLink())));

                break;
            // return true;
        }


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void launchProductDetail(int position) {

        Product product = (Product) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductDetailActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("Product", product);


        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void update() {

        ProductRetrieverImpl retriever = mainTask.getRetriever();

        String price = retriever.getBySelectorPrice2();


        double newPrice = Double.parseDouble(price.substring(1));

        if (newPrice != product.getPrice()) {

            if (newPrice < product.getPrice()) {

                product.setPriceIncrease(false);

                priceUpdate(product, newPrice);
            } else {

                product.setPriceIncrease(true);
                priceUpdate(product, newPrice);

            }


        }

    }


    public class JSOUP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            dialog.setMessage("loading.....");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/black--decker-ni-cad-cordless-drill-driver---18v-623805").get();
                Element element = document.select("#offerPrice_262795").first();
                ben = element.text();


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("anything selected?", ben);
            System.out.println(ben);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat ....!!!

Comment: Issue was caused by website having both mobile and desktop versions and thus different html tags